# Should I use one LINQ DataContext or many?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, performance

For a large project, would it make sense to have one datacontext which maps out your database, which you can interact with from your classes?

Or would it make more sense to split this up into small datacontexts which are focused on the specific tasks within the database that will be required.

I'm curious as to the performance.  It's my understanding that the datacontext itself is a very lightweight object, which only initializes its internal collections as they're required etc.  Therfore dealing with a datacontext with many defintions but only two tables of data should be as fast as dealing with a special datacontext with only those two tables in it.

I also think you would benefit at the JIT time, as the first class to do data access will compile your dc which is now available to all classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226127/multiple-single-instance-of-linq-to-sql-datacontext

Comment: similar but not the same :)  Cheers for linking me though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking about design versus runtime pattern. I general I'd say *no*:

While it may be possible to partition your database into multiple data contexts, then that would be desirable if and only if there was zero overlap between the two contexts.

*Overlap is Bad*

e.g. you have a `WebsiteContext` and an `AdminContext`. The `WebsiteContext` is for displaying `Product` and fulfilling `Order`s. A `WebsiteUser` is attached to an `Order`. The `AdminContext` is for your `Staff` members to process refunds for cancelled `Orders`, which also reference `WebsiteUser`. The `AdminContext` also needs to reset passwords and update other details for the `WebsiteUser`.

You're thinking of doing this because you don't want the website to process or even know about `Returns`

```
WebsiteContext
Product -- Order -- WebsiteUser

AdminContext
Staff -- Returns -- Order -- WebsiteUser
```

In the above, we can see we're duplicating many objects in the different Data Contexts. This smells bad, and it really indicates that artificially dividing the database into different data contexts is a the wrong decision. Do you have >2 databases after all, or just the one? The duplication violates the DRY principle (Dont Repeat Yourself) because WebsiteContext.WebsiteUser is not the same as AdminContext.WebsiteUser and in all likelihood the code is going to be messy when something needs to care which one they're referencing.

---

The Linq Data Context is just an OR mapper, and needs to be treated as a fancy black box that makes writing some of the data access code easier. Some linq demos make it look like you no longer need the other layers, but a program of any complexity still benefits from a layered design.

You're probably better off treating the Linq objects as just objects for easily transferring data and create a Domain layer that hides them as an implementation detail. Have a read of DDD - Domain Driven Design.

On their own, just using the Linq objects from the UI most resembles the `Transaction Script` pattern. In such a case you'd still benefit from having a logic layer that takes care of the details.

---

While you may not want the responsibility of a context to be so broad, the data context is just a representation of the database. It's not a security mechanism, and it can't prevent you from corrupting the data.

Answer (score 1):

From a "repository pattern" angle, there is something to be said for having separate aggregates and minimizing the navigation properties between aggregates. I'm not 100% sure what that something **is** though... at the moment I'm *considering* using a moderately-sized dbml, with multiple repositories using it (the UI doesn't use the datacontexts directly - only the repository classes), with the navigation properties marked internal so the DAL can use them... Maybe...