# LinqToSql duplicate records inserting with relationships

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql, async-await

I have a weird situation I cannot figure out the cause to. In start up on a Windows Phone app, I have the following code where I simply create some `Group`s, then create some `Account`s where the previously created `Group`s are related objects to the `Account`s.

```
public async static void SampleData()
{
     var grp1 = await Manager.GroupManager.SaveGroupAsync(new Group { GroupName = "Wells Fargo" });
     var grp2 = await Manager.GroupManager.SaveGroupAsync(new Group { GroupName = "Chase" });
     var grp3 = await Manager.GroupManager.SaveGroupAsync(new Group { GroupName = "Citi" });

     var acct1 = await Manager.AccountManager.SaveAccountAsync(new Account { AccountName = "Spending", AccountType = (int)Enums.AccountType.Banking, Group = grp1 }); //0
     var acct2 = await Manager.AccountManager.SaveAccountAsync(new Account { AccountName = "Credit Card", AccountType = (int)Enums.AccountType.Credit, Group = grp1 }); //1
     var acct3 = await Manager.AccountManager.SaveAccountAsync(new Account { AccountName = "Mortgage", AccountType = (int)Enums.AccountType.Banking, Group = grp2 }); //2
     var acct4 = await Manager.AccountManager.SaveAccountAsync(new Account { AccountName = "Savings", AccountType = (int)Enums.AccountType.Banking, Group = grp2 }); //3
     var acct5 = await Manager.AccountManager.SaveAccountAsync(new Account { AccountName = "Spending", AccountType = (int)Enums.AccountType.Banking, Group = grp2 }); //4
     var acct6 = await Manager.AccountManager.SaveAccountAsync(new Account { AccountName = "Credit Card", AccountType = (int)Enums.AccountType.Credit, Group = grp3 }); //5
}
```

Respective methods:

**Managers**

```
public async static Task<Group> SaveGroupAsync(Group group)
{
    await DataAccess.GroupData.SaveGroupAsync(group);

    return group;
}

public async static Task<Account> SaveAccountAsync(Account account)
{
    await DataAccess.AccountData.SaveAccountAsync(account);

    return account;
}
```

**Data Access**

```
public async static Task<Group> SaveGroupAsync(Group group)
{
    using (var dc = new CbmDataContext(DBHelper.LocalConnectionString))
    {
        if (group.GroupId == 0)
            dc.Groups.InsertOnSubmit(group);

        dc.SubmitChanges();

        return group;
    }
}

public async static Task<Account> SaveAccountAsync(Account account)
{
    using (var dc = new CbmDataContext(DBHelper.LocalConnectionString))
    {
        if (account.AccountId == 0)
            dc.Accounts.InsertOnSubmit(account);

        dc.SubmitChanges();

        return account;
    }
}
```

When the first 3 Save's for the Group run, I see 3 new objects inserted. This is my expected behavior. When the code runs for the **first** new Account, I see the new Account, but I also see a NEW entry in the Groups table for the referenced account. I end up with 2 Groups with the same name.

What am I doing wrong that is allowing this to occur? I can see the Account.GroupId is set to the Id of the group that is set below.

Answer (score 0):

So I stumbled across a *solution*, but not so much an answer.

I found the direction from a comment on one of the answers here - [LINQ to SQL - where does your DataContext live?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196253/linq-to-sql-where-does-your-datacontext-live)

> As I understand it, you still want one DataContext to manage the lifecycle of an Entity for SubmitChanges() to work correctly without re-attaching your Entity. Correct? Fetch->Edit->Submit. In that case, your DataContext lives outside method scope and 'using' is less valuable.

On my BaseData class, which the other DAOs inherit from, I threw a static instance of my data context, and just removed all the usings from the DAO's, so now they are using the same data context.

```
public static CbmDataContext dc = new CbmDataContext(DBHelper.LocalConnectionString);
```

So I suppose because I'm using the same instance of a data context here, it's able to keep track of entities better, versus new instances.

Comment: Be aware that using a single static `DataContext` is not a recommended practice. It would be better to create a single `DataContext` at the beginning of your `SampleData` method and disposing it (using a `using` clause) at the end of it.